# Stopping arrow keys from selecting button

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a program where when I press the arrow keys on my keyboard, a picture I placed on the form, will move accordingly.
Everything was working fine, the picture was moving on the form when I press the arrow keys. The problem happens when i placed a button on the form. When I press the arrow keys it just selects the button instead of making the picture move. Does anyone know how i can press the arrow keys without selecting the button?

I have tried changing the TabIndex to 0 and the TabStop to false but it didn't help, i still couldn't use the arrow keys to move the picture.

Comment: Shouldn't tabindex be set to -1 for this?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the tabIndex to -1 on the button. Elements with a negative tabindex will not be used for tabbing.

```
<button tabIndex="-1">Click</button>
```

Comment: I cant seem to change it to -1.

Comment: How do you add the button to the form? Can you create a jsfiddle so that I can see what exactly is happening?